# How to use GAE with firebase hosting

Tags: django, google-app-engine, firebase-hosting

I have a GAE project created using Django. I also have a static website for the project's homepage hosted on firebase.

If someone visits `www.myproj.com`, they should see the static webpage hosted on firebase.

If someone visits `www.myproj.com/j/64gj37`, they should see the response delivered by the django project.

I am looking for something like this:

```
configuration:
url: /
redirect_to: https://myproj-homepage.firebaseapp.com/

url: /(.+)$
project: myproj-django
```

What should be the configuration for `dispatch.yaml` and `app.yaml`? I am currently using a simplistic `app.yaml`

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37
default_expiration: "4d 5h"
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app. 
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted 
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static 
# files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

Comment: I assume you don't want the client to see the `https://myproj-homepage.firebaseapp.com/` URL in their browser, right?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen correct, the user should see `www.myproj.com` for the homepage.

Comment: Rewrites usually only work on the same host, while redirects (which are sent to the client as a 301 or 302 response) can go to a different server. For example that's how rewrites and redirects on Firebase Hosting work. The only way I know do get something like a cross-server rewrite is if the server reads the contents from the other server/URL, and then sends it back. But I didn't immediately see a GAE/Django module to do that.

Comment: I am open for any suggestions. I think this is not an obscure use case. Usually any Saas company will have a static landing homepage (for eg: `bitly.com`), which usually contains company info, pricing etc. But a specific path like `bitly.com/t64h3` is handled by their business logic. The static landing page can have separate repository and their dynamic pages can have a separate repo.

Comment: Can I use two separate services for static and dynamic pages? Or should I merge my repos to show both the static and dynamic pages from a common repo (and common hosting)

Comment: another example is `about.me` and `https://about.me/bigkidd`. I believe they have a static homepage and dynamic subpages.

Comment: Typically I'd split `api.mything.com` from `(www.)mything.com` and then serve the microservices from the former. You can also do subpaths with Firebase Hosting doing the rewrites, but only to Cloud Functions and Cloud Run at the moment.